# What is the difference between gc() and rm()

Tags: r, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am periodically cleaning the memory in R using a call to `rm(list=ls())`.
Do I need to call the garbage collector `gc()` after that?

What is the difference between these 2 functions? Does `gc()` call `rm()` for certain variables?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

First, it is important to note that the two are very different in that `gc` does not delete *any* variables that you are still using- it only frees up the memory for ones that you no longer have access to (whether removed using `rm()` or, say, created in a function that has since returned). Running `gc()` will never make you lose variables.

The question of whether you should call `gc()` after calling `rm()`, though, is a good one. The [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/gc.html) for gc helpfully notes:

> A call of gc causes a garbage collection to take place. This will also take place automatically without user intervention, and the primary purpose of calling gc is for the report on memory usage.
>
> However, it can be useful to call gc after a large object has been removed, as this may prompt R to return memory to the operating system.

So the answer is that it can be good to call `gc()` (and at the very least, can't hurt), even though it would likely be triggered anyway (if not right away, then soon).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Generally speaking, is R automatic garbage collection considered as good? (as robust as java's one for instance)

Comment: That's a difficult question to answer, I'm not sure. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467201/forcing-garbage-collection-to-run-in-r-with-the-gc-command) is useful.

Comment: Generally you should not have to call gc, and it's unlikely to make much difference if you do.

Comment: @hadley That doesn’t align at all with my experience. On the contrary, R often causes my operating system to swap even after large objects (~ a few hundred MiBs) are no longer available. Manually calling `gc()`, however, avoids this. Using available memory is OK, unnecessarily swapping really is not, since it negatively impacts the usability of the OS. State of the art GCs handle this much better.

Comment: Seconding @KonradRudolph's comment - in some recent work I've been noticing enormous amounts of memory consumed by a function's local variables. The memory is not freed when the variables go out of scope, as it would be in other languages. I had to call `gc()`.

Comment: For those happening upon this question today and subsequently reading this answer, I just removed some variables from my environment - which took up ~15GB in memory - yet R was still struggling to store any further variables despite having removed the large ones that I no longer needed.  I then ran `gc()`, waited a minute, and then discovered that all of the memory had been reallocated to my session, thus allowing me to save variables once again. I'd like to reiterate what the `gc` documentation states: `...it can be useful to call gc after a large object has been removed...`

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like to include the `gc()` in loops to free up some RAM when the loops start filling up the available space. Something like

```
for(i in 1:1000){
res[[i]] = some operation
gc()
}
```

Comment: Please be aware to calling gc() comes with a hefty performance penalty in the order of 100ms per call. So in this case your code will run about 100 seconds longer than necessary :)

Answer (score 2):

Re ThankGoat's comment on gc penalty, while this is true, one could of course decide to call gc every N iterations in a loop (where N can be parameterised in a number of ways). For loops where number of iterations is large, but resource usage within a given iteration is more modest, it may well not be necessary to do GC each and every iteration in order to regain desired performance.

Of course, if you're looping with a very large number of very high usage iterations, it's a different story, but at that stage it may well the case that the code simply needs to be vectorised and / or maybe even written in another language.