# How do I clean up R memory without restarting my PC?

Tags: r

I am running my code in R (under Windows) which involves a lot of in-memory data. I tried to use `rm(list=ls())` to clean up memory, but seems the memory is still occupied and I cannot rerun my code. I tried to close the R and restart R again, but it is the same. It seems that memory is still occupied, as when I run the code, it says it can't allocate memory (but it could at the first time). The memory only seems to get cleaned up after I restart my PC.

Is there any way to clean up the memory so that I can rerun my code without restarting my PC every time?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what your code is doing? If you're opening and not closing a lot of text connections, that could be a problem.

Comment: Open your Task Manager and under Processses sort according to Memory. That way you'll see if R is hogging up RAM. I suspect you have a rogue process, maybe you're running something in parallel?

Comment: Thanks, it is the R occupying about 1GB, so how can I clean up memory without shutting down R? I do have read.table and read.zoo in my codes which read quite large files... but after rm(list=ls()), why the memory is still not yet cleaned up?

Comment: R's garbage collection "marks" the RAM as available. Up to your OS to reclaim that.

Comment: Thank you. In that case, why when I run the codes for first time, there is no memory allocation warning, but when I run the same set of code the second time after run rm(list=ls()) and restart my R, there is memory allocation warning?

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example? For instance, create a very big matrix of random numbers and run the script twice to see if you get the same behavior. This could serve as a benchmark of other users to see if they experience the same problem.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use the function `gc()`. A call of `gc()` causes a garbage collection to take place. It can be useful to call `gc()` after a large object has been removed, as this may prompt R to return memory to the operating system.
`gc()` also return a summary of the occupy memory.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what `gc` does. The answer is valid, but a bit short.

Comment: +1, however the OP experiences the problem that even after closing R and restarting it, the memory is still not freed. Closing R altogether should be just as effective as calling `gc`.

Comment: I've posted my answer to clear memory occupied by R. I would also like to point you to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813753/what-is-the-difference-between-gc-and-rm

Answer (score 39):

I came under the same problem with R. I dig a bit and come with a solution, that we need to restart R session to fully clean the memory/RAM. For this, you can use a simple code after removing everything from your workspace. the code is as follows :

```
rm(list = ls())

.rs.restartR()
```

Comment: I guess this an internal function of RStudio and does not work with "plain vanilla" R. Good to know anyhow :-)

Comment: The namespace of this function is attached to the search path in RStudio - see `search()`):  `e <- as.environment("tools:rstudio"); e$.rs.restartR()`

Comment: Does this happen automatically when restarting an R Session?

Comment: this worked better for me than gc() when processing some large raster data that was plugging up temporary memory

Answer (score 13):

Use `ls()` function to see what R objects are occupying space. use rm("objectName") to clear the objects from R memory that is no longer required. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813753/what-is-the-difference-between-gc-and-rm) too.

Answer (score 8):

```
memory.size(max=T) # gives the amount of memory obtained by the OS
[1] 1800
memory.size(max=F) # gives the amount of memory being used
[1] 261.17
```

Using Paul's example,

```
m = matrix(runif(10e7), 10000, 1000)
```

Now

```
memory.size(max=F)
[1] 1024.18
```

To clear up the memory

```
gc()
memory.size(max=F)
[1] 184.86
```

In other words, the memory should now be clear again. If you loop a code, it is a good idea to add a `gc()` as the last line of your loop, so that the memory is cleared up before starting the next iteration.

Comment: Note that memory.size() is Windows specific and will return value of "Inf" if run on a Linux platform. The function gc() will still work with either.

Comment: Perfect explanation and the Windows part is true, but useful function for cleaning up memory inside apply family functions and loops.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding this for reference in case anybody needs to restart and immediatly run a command.

I'm using this approach just to clear RAM from the system. Make sure you have deleted all objects no longer required. Maybe `gc()` can also help before hand. But nothing will clear RAM better as restarting the R session.

```
library(rstudioapi)
restartSession(command = "print('x')")
```

Answer (score 3):

An example under Linux (Fedora 16) shows that memory is freed when R is closed:

```
$ free -m                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached                                                                                                                                                                    
Mem:          3829       2854        974          0        344       1440                                                                                                                                                                    
-/+ buffers/cache:       1069       2759                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Swap:         4095         85       4010
```

2854 megabytes is used. Next I open an R session and create a large matrix of random numbers:

```
m = matrix(runif(10e7), 10000, 1000)
```

when the matrix is created, 3714 MB is used:

```
$ free -m                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached                                                                                                                                                                    
Mem:          3829       3714        115          0        344       1442                                                                                                                                                                    
-/+ buffers/cache:       1927       1902                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Swap:         4095         85       4010
```

After closing the R session, I nicely get back the memory I used (2856 MB free):

```
$ free -m                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached                                                                                                                                                                    
Mem:          3829       2856        972          0        344       1442                                                                                                                                                                    
-/+ buffers/cache:       1069       2759                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Swap:         4095         85       4010
```

Ofcourse you use Windows, but you could repeat this excercise in Windows and report how the available memory develops before and after you create this large dataset in R.

Answer (score 2):

There is only so much you can do with rm() and gc(). As suggested by Gavin Simpson, even if you free the actual memory in R, Windows often won't reclaim it until you close R or it is needed because all the apparent Windows memory fills up.

This usually isn't a problem. However, if you are running large loops this can sometimes lead to fragmented memory in the long term, such that even if you free the memory and restart R - the fragmented memory may prevent you allocating large chunks of memory. Especially if other applications were allocated fragmented memory while you were running R. rm() and gc() may delay the inevitable, but more RAM is better.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it helpful to go into my "tmp" folder and delete all hanging rsession files. This usually frees any memory that seems to be "stuck".

Answer (score 0):

Launch Terminal, check location of previously saved R objects:

```
ls -a
```

Then, remove previously saved data:

```
rm -rf .RData
rm -rf .RDataTmp
```

Lauch R Studio, previously saved objects shouldn't appear under Environment tab.

you could also try `gc()` on terminal.