# R reticulate, how do I clear a python object from memory?

Tags: r, python-imaging-library, reticulate

I've created a function using some python functionality via the `reticulate` package, specifically opening an image using `PIL`:

```
image <- "~/Desktop/image.jpg"
pil.image <- reticulate::import( "PIL.Image", convert = FALSE )
img <- pil.image$open( image )
```

I then do a few things with the image (I'm extracting several crops), which works fine. Here's an example of what I'm doing (`outputs` is a data frame of crops I need, so `crop.grid` is just a vector of 4 numbers.

```
crop.grid <- c( outputs$x.start[x],
                outputs$y.start[x],
                outputs$x.stop[x],
                outputs$y.stop[x] )
crop.grid <- as.integer( crop.grid )
crop.grid <- reticulate::r_to_py( crop.grid )
output.array <- img$crop( box = crop.grid )
output.array$save( output.filename )
```

After this, I want to clear the image from memory (the images I'm opening are very large, so take a lot of memory). I try closing the image in python:

```
img$close()
```

As well as in R:

```
rm( img )
gc()
```

And replacing the object with something I know to be very small.

```
img <- reticulate::r_to_py( 1L )
```

All of these things run fine, but my RAM still registers as being very full. I try them with each of the python objects I've created, but the only thing that clears the RAM effectively is restarting the R session.

I know that within `python` I'd be better off opening the image using `with` in order to clear it at the end of the process, but I'm not sure how to implement that using `reticulate`.

---

--- UPDATE with an analogous `python` version:

If I do the above in python directly:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open( "/home/user/Desktop/image.jpg" )
output = img.crop( [0,0,100,100] )
```

And then close things:

```
output.close()
img.close()
```

The memory clears. The same thing doesn't work from within R though. ie:

```
output.array$close()
img$close()
gc() # for good measure
```

Doesn't clear the memory.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it all into [with](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/introduction.html#with-contexts) - sth like `with(pil.image$open( image ) %as% img, {
  img$crop(r_to_py( c(0,0,100,100)))$save("myfile.jpg")
})`?

Comment: @lukeA I hadn't, but I have now. It runs fine, but still the same problem with the RAM being full. Interestingly it's the `output.array<-img$crop(box=crop.grid)` step that loads up the memory, but I run that step repeatedly in my function, and each iteration doesn't seem to re-read the image (only the first iteration takes any significant time). closing `output.array`, `rm`, and `gc` still seem to do nothing to clear RAM.

Comment: Maybe wrap it into with, too? E.g. `with(pil.image$open( image ) %as% img, {
    with(img$crop(r_to_py( c(0,0,100,100))) %as% output.array, {
      output.array$save("myfile.jpg")
    })
  })` - just trial&error.

Comment: Fair call, but still no dice. I think `with` is operating in `R` here, so only the R object is removed. The python object (I assume sitting in an environment in the background) still remains.

Comment: This is not specific to the `reticulate` package. Chances are your objects are indeed deleted. But the OS gave memory to R and even though that memory is now internally freed by R, R hasn't released it / given it back to the OS. There are lots of posts about this. The easiest solution is to close the R session. If you do not want to do that, I often see that you can call `gc` to free the memory but in my experience this is not a reliable way to get R to give back the RAM...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579765/how-to-clean-up-memory-not-need-to-restart-my-pc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813753/what-is-the-difference-between-gc-and-rm

Comment: @antoine-sac thanks for the response. You'll see in my question that I did try using `gc()` in `R` to no avail. Unfortunately, since (I assume) `reticulate` initiates an external `python` session, that session may be where the memory allocation issue lies, so running `gc()` in the `R` session makes no difference. Restarting `R` clearly closes the `python` session properly, so a `reticulate` function to do that without restarting `R` would be enough, but something to properly clear the object without closing that session would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do 3 things:

1. Explicitly create the object in Python:

   ```
   py_env <- py_run_string(
       paste(
           "from PIL import Image",
           "img = Image.open('~/Desktop/image.jpg')",
           sep = "\n"
       ),
       convert = FALSE
   )
   img <- py_env$img
   ```
2. When you're done with the image, first delete the Python object.

   ```
   py_run_string("del img")
   ```
3. Then run the Python garbage collector.

   ```
   py_gc <- import("gc")
   py_gc$collect()
   ```

Steps 2 and 3 are the important ones. Step 1 is just so you have a name to delete. If there's a way to delete "implicit" Python objects (can't think of a better term), that would save some boilerplate.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks very much for the response. As I said, I was hoping to do this with `reticulate`'s more R-side functionality, rather than using `py_run_string`. I can certainly do this with `py_run_string`, and since there have been no answers here suggesting a direct way around the problem, I think that's probably the way I need to go. I'm going to award you the bounty, since you have indeed provided a solution, even though it's not the one I was hoping for. Just a note though, I've found that running eg `img.close()` in python seems to trigger a garbage cleanup, without an explicit call.