# Freeing up resources while running loops in h2o

Tags: r, h2o

I am running a loop to upload a csv file from my local machine, convert it to a h2o data frame, then run a h2o model. I then remove the h2o data frame from my r environment and the loop continues. These data frames are massive so I can only have one data frame loaded at a time (hence the reason for me removing the data frame from my environment).

My problem is that h2o creates temporary files which quickly max out my memory. I know I can restart my r session, but is there another way to flush this out in code so my loop can run happily? When I look at my task manager the all my memory is sucked up in Java(TM) Platform SE Binary.

Comment: What method are you using to remove your data frame at the moment?

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm using `rm(h2o_df)`

Comment: Some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579765/how-do-i-clean-up-r-memory-without-restarting-my-pc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) on the OS reclaiming the RAM that is freed up by R. Would be better off restarting your session.

Comment: Have you tried running `gc()` after `rm(h2o_df)`? That usu. works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the object from the R session using `rm(h2o_df)` will eventually trigger garbage collection in R and the delete will be propagated to H2O. I don't think this is ideal, however.

The recommended way is to use `h2o.rm` or for your particular use case, it seems like `h2o.removeAll` would be the best (takes care of everything, models, data..).