# Memory issues in R. Can I clear memory with rm(list=ls()) and .rs.restartR() while rendering a site in rmarkdown?

Tags: r

I have a Rmd file with 3 sections, a, b and c. I can run everything up till the end of section b just fine with an output html document generated.

However, when I get to the section c I encounter memory issues. I am able to run this 3rd section on it's own.

So, I added a line before section c in my script starts with `rm(list=ls())`. However, this doesn't solve the problem which is confusing since this section will run on it's own if there is no code beforehand.

I found a suggestion for `.rs.restartR()` over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670269/clear-memory-allocated-by-r-session-gc-doesnt-help) but presumably restarting R will interupt my Rmd file being rendered.

Is there a prescribed approach here?

Some older SO posts mention calling `gc()` but that did not help.

If I can run sections a and b on their own and then section c on it's own, can I not somehow render the whole Rmd document, sections a through c by clearing memory before the code in section c runs?

Comment: A workaround might be to first render PDFs section by section and [combine them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467602/6574038) later.

Comment: Thanks but I'm rendering this as html since it's being hosted by my webserver, so trying to complete in a oner. Thanks for the suggestion though