# RODBC not freeing up memory after rm() and gc()

Tags: sql-server, r, memory-leaks, rodbc

I am connecting to a SQL server database in R using the RODBC package and making multiple calls to the database, doing something with the result, writing the result to disk and removing all variables. I then call gc() and close the channel before starting the next iteration. This is roughly shown below.

```
for(i in 1:1000){
    ch <- odbcConnect("some dsn")

    result = sqlQuery(ch, 'SELECT * from table where some_condition = i')
    #some processing here...


    saveRDS(result, 'result.rdata')
    # this should remove all object in memory
    rm(result)
    gc()
    odbcClose(ch)
}
```

My problem is that as the loop progresses, the amount of memory being used by R gets larger and larger (as revelaed in the windows Resouce Monitor), despite the total size of the objects in the global environment not increasing. Eventually, I use up all of the memory available on my machine (16gb, Windows 7, 64 bit) and the process crashes.

- **Why is this happenning?**
- **How can I force R to free up the memory without restarting R?**

Things I have tried that did not work:

- multiple calls to gc() as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467334/366502.
- changing the buffsize, rows_at_time and believeNRows arguments in sqlQuery()

  > sessionInfo()
  >   R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
  >   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
  >   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

  locale:
  [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252

  attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

  other attached packages:
   [1] data.table_1.9.4 DBI_0.3.1        rsqlserver_1.0   rClr_0.7-4       text_0.0.0.9000  stringr_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.3       RODBC_1.3-11     rvest_0.2.0      tomr_0.0.0.9000

  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
   [1] Rcpp_0.12.0     lattice_0.20-31 XML_3.98-1.2    slam_0.1-32     grid_3.2.0      chron_2.3-47    R6_2.1.1        magrittr_1.5    httr_1.0.0      stringi_0.5-5   reshape2_1.4.1  NLP_0.1-8       Matrix_1.2-1    tools_3.2.0
  [15] parallel_3.2.0  tm_0.6-2

Comment: Might be worth trying [RSQLServer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLServer/index.html), and if you don't see the same problem then you'd (a) have a solution and (b) know that the problem is probably in RODBC's C code somewhere.

Comment: My eventual solution to this has been to use Rscript.exe and start a fresh instances of R for each iteration of the loop.