# Memory cleaning problems in R

Tags: r, memory-management, garbage-collection, ram

I want to freeing up some memory after creating some cforest objects, which seems to occupy my memory even after deleting them from my environment like this:

```
cf_object <- NULL
```

I've already tried

```
rm(list = ls())
```

and

```
gc()
```

and

```
gc(reset = T)
```

I can only get rid of those occupied bytes with restarting R studio.

I am using Microsoft R Open 3.2.3 under 64 bit Windows 7.
(Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit))

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `ls()` show you after running `rm(list = ls())` ?  I'm assuming that when you exited R Studio you opted to not save the workspace?

Comment: Why do you need to free up some memory? Does external software need that memory?

Comment: See the following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467201/forcing-garbage-collection-to-run-in-r-with-the-gc-command?lq=1), which covers and links to a number of relevant issues.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen rm(list = ls()) returns character(0)

Comment: @Roland I need to create several cforests, for which I've got 16Gb-s of memory. I could grow bigger trees in an automated process (with a shorter running period) if I could manage to clean up the RAM within the process. Until that point I'll generate smaller forests with flushing the RAM manually :(

Comment: R's garbage collection should take care of releasing the memory when needed. Manual input from the user is normally not required for this to work.