# rm(list = ls()) doesn't work inside a function. Why?

Tags: r, garbage-collection, workspace

I'm trying to create a function that will, simultaneously, clear the workspace and the memory so that, rather than having to type "rm(list = ls()); gc()", I can type just one function. But rm(list = ls()) doesn't work when it's called from within a function. Why? Is there any way around this?

```
> # Let's create an object
> x = 0
> ls()
[1] "x"
> 
> # This works fine:
> rm(list = ls()); gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 269975 14.5     592000 31.7   427012 22.9
Vcells 474745  3.7    1023718  7.9   808322  6.2
> ls()
character(0)
> 
> ## But if I try to create a function to do exactly the same thing, it doesn't work
> # Creating the object again
> x = 0
> ls()
[1] "x"
> 
> #Here's the function (notice that I have to exclude the function name from the 
# list argument or the function would remove itself):
> clear = function(list = ls()[-which(ls() == "clear")]){
+   rm(list = list); gc()
+ }
> ls()
[1] "clear" "x"    
>
```

Comment: inside a function R creates a new environment for you - so it isn't working in the global environment

Comment: a) you haven't run the function. b) inside a function, `rm` will only be evaluated in the scope of the function. So it won't delete anything in your global environment. See `?rm` and notice it has an `envir=` argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rm` is actually working, however since you're using it inside a function, it only removes all objects pertaining to the environment of that function.

Add `envir = .GlobalEnv` parameter to both calls:

```
rm(list = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

should do it.

I also recommend you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467201/forcing-garbage-collection-to-run-in-r-with-the-gc-command) other question about gc() as i believe it's not a good practice to call it explicitly unless you **really** need it.

Comment: In this case I really need it.

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia You must do something truly esoteric if you need to call `gc` manually.