# When I try to clear the workspace in R console, it always asks through a pop-up. How can I disable the pop-up?

Tags: r

When I try to clear the workspace in R console, it always pops up a dialog saying:

```
All objects in the workspace will be removed. Are you sure you want to proceed?
```

[image]

Can I have a way to disable this popup?

Comment: Is this R or is this RStudio? What method do you use to clear workspace? Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some suggestions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996090/how-to-disable-save-workspace-image-prompt-in-r)) depending on your platform. Looks like passing the "no-save" option when invoking R is your best bet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996252/8273813

Comment: The above occurs not when I am exiting, but any time I am trying to clear the workspace. I am able to invoke the no-save option but still have the above issue.

Comment: As a workaround until you find a proper solution for Console, you could add a function to .Rprofile. This might actually be an advantage since you can exclude objects. Here's an example adapted from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966847/rmlist-ls-doesnt-work-inside-a-function-why).

`clr <- function() {
  rm(list = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)[-which(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv) %in% c("clr"))], envir = .GlobalEnv)`
}