# Calling different sections of an external script through "source"

Tags: r, workflow

I have just finished writing a set of R scripts. There is one master file and 5 additional external r files called by the `source` function. I was wondering whether it is possible to unify the five external scripts into one single file; dividing the entire code into five sections run into different moments.

Is it possible to do so by using `source`?. If not, which strategy do you suggest?

Comment: well, that's the answer :) I hadn't thought about embedding entire parts of code just for call them later.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @flodel said in the comment, write functions. There are a few previous answers that are worth checking out:

1. [Workflow for statistical analysis and report writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429907/workflow-for-statistical-analysis-and-report-writing)
2. [writing functions vs. line-by-line interpretation in an R workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365974/writing-functions-vs-line-by-line-interpretation-in-an-r-workflow)
3. [How do you combine "Revision Control" with "Workflow" for R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286831/how-do-you-combine-revision-control-with-workflow-for-r)