# How to keep track of input / output files in R

Tags: r, project-management, pipeline

I write many R scripts producing output that is later used as input to another R script. For example, I may write script `a.R`, save resulting table as an `a-result.rda` object, write script `b.R`, import the `a-result.rda` object, modify the table, maybe plot some graphs, save new table as `table.csv`, and so on..

I find it cumbersome to identify the R script (here `a.R`) which the particular `table.csv` (indirectly) originated from.

So far, my solution is a shortcut function in my `.bashrc` that allows me to pinpoint the immediate parent of an output object:

```
findinR(){ find . -iname '*.R' -exec grep -r $1 {} + ; }
```

If I am looking for the origin of `table.csv`, I can do `findinR table.csv`, and as output I will get the path of the `b.R` script, along with the corresponding `write.csv(..` line. Then, in `b.R` script I notice that `table.csv` is a modified version of `a-result.rda`, so I do `findinR a-result.rda` and I find script `a.R`. This is working for 'shallow' I/O dependencies, but makes me want to kill myself when dealing with more layers.

Does anyone use/know of a text-based system or software that would allow me to produce (automatically or at least semi-automatically) I/O flowcharts or pipelines? So that I can record the history of the files generated during analysis?

**EDIT:** Some additional, potentially crucial details:

1. I am not particularly interested in reporting tools or rerunning the entire analysis in one go (for smaller projects, I use `knitr`, but for more complex dependency-heavy workflows it's too cumbersome). I work with genomic data, which makes it impossible to rerun parts of the analysis.
2. The input / output scripts/files have unstandardized names. I almost never repeat the same steps, so templates wouldn't help much.
3. The final output can be anything, not only a `.csv` file, but most often it's `.rds` or `.rdata` / `.rda`.
4. The only thing I need is a (semi-)automatics way to record the workflow, not necessarily rerun it with a different input.

**EDIT2:** I tried automatically generating txt files by grepping lines that incude `save()`, `load()`, `write.csv()`, `read.csv()`, `pdf()`, etc. However, I often use `paste` to generate my file names, so the corresponding lines in the code are not descriptive enough to be able to identify the file.

Comment: Some good ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429907/workflow-for-statistical-analysis-and-report-writing. Also you could write lines starting with # in your output csv files. These can be ignored when reading back into R. See `?read.csv` specifically the option comment.char

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, the thread is 4 years old and answers a slightly different question :( I am not so much interested in reporting tools per se (in a fresher thread `knitr` would replace makefiles and Sweave) nor rerunning code for the entire analysis. I'll update my question with more details. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question. I would not try to grep the source codes, it looks highly complicated, messy and prone to errors. What about generating a new file `example.version` every time that you create a `example.csv `, `example.rds` or `example.rdata`? This file would be a one liner that would include the script name and useful info, such as the date of creation, the git/csv version of the repo (if you use those), the time required to generate the csv file... It looks like this would solve your problem in a relatively easy way. You could write wrappers for it, like `my.save()`, `my.write.csv()`..